# Correct way to handle SharePoint URL spaces in pl/sql procedures

Tags: oracle, url, sharepoint, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to specify a file path to a SharePoint location.
What is the best way to handle spaces in URL if URL is like this for example?

```
file_path_ varchar2(2000) := 'https://business123.sharepoint.com/sites/TEST/Private Documents/Export Test';
```

Original URL has %20 in between Private and Documents and Export and Test.
I've tried concatenation with `|| '' ||` and using `" "` inside `' '`.
Is there maybe a way to generate a different URL from SharePoint? The user that is trying to write to folder location has full access and permissions so I know it's not that, that is preventing me from writing to that folder.

Does anyone have any cool ideas?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.3) describes URL components and specifies that they should contain several characters from ASCII set (alphanumeric and some symbols). Others (including space) should be percent-encoded with their hex representation. What is the issue with `%20`?

Comment: @astentx it pretty much says that the file path is wrong....though I can access it without a problem with a use that is trying to write to it. An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [UTL_URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_URL.html#GUID-1AD609BE-A0DE-41C3-8F86-4C11BCEA658B) package to escape illegal characters like spaces:

> ```
> utl_url.escape('http://www.acme.com/a url with space.html')
> ```
>
> returns:
>
> ```
> http://www.acme.com/a%20url%20with%20space.html
> ```